# Do class objects have data types in c++?

Tags: c++, class, object

I know this is a dumb question but I can't help asking it. Do objects from classes have data types in c++? Is it a certain defined type? Also, can an object array have multiple data types?

For e.g: Normal (Without Objects)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int array1[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
}
```

So.. <strike>Normal</strike> With Objects

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class thisIsRandom {    /*Useful code */ };
int main() 
{
    thisIsRandom array1[5]; // = has multiple data types, like int, double..?
}
```

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes): *"A class is a user-defined type."*

Comment: In C++, the stuff in your first example has objects, because ints and arrays of int are objects.

Comment: Yes, yes, and no. See also: polymorphism and variants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Methinks you have a misunderstanding of how C++ works compared to other languages:

The meaning of the term "Object" in C++ differs from languages: **in C++ every value is an "object"**, regardless of whether or not the value is an instance of a `class` (or `struct`) or not.

Compare to other languages:

- JavaScript/ECMASCript: An `Object` specifically refers to complex/non-scalar values that derive from the `Object` built-in, but not other types like `Number`.
- C# / .NET: An instance of a type that derives from `System.Object` (i.e. every `class` instance) but also every non-scalar `struct` value and "boxed" value type.
- Java: An instance of a type that derives from `java.Object` (i.e. every `class` instance) but not unboxed values.

C++ has a strict definition of the term "object", from the 2013 specification (section `1.8` "The C++ object model") (emphasis mine):

> The constructs in a C++ program create, destroy, refer to, access, and manipulate objects. **An object is a region of storage.** [Note: A function is not an object, regardless of whether or not it occupies storage in the way that objects do. — end note]. **An object is created by a definition (3.1)**, by a `new-expression` (5.3.4) or by the implementation (12.2) when needed. The properties of an object are determined when the object is created. An object can have a name (Clause 3). An object has a storage duration (3.7) which influences its lifetime (3.8). **An object has a type** (3.9). The term object type refers to the type with which the object is created. Some objects are polymorphic (10.3); the implementation generates information associated with each such object that makes it possible to determine that object’s type during program execution. For other objects, the interpretation of the values found therein is determined by the type of the expressions (Clause 5) used to access them

So all these are "objects":

```
int x                // object of type 'int' named 'x'
vector<my_class> y   // object of type 'vector<my_class>' named 'y'
```

In other languages (like VB6 and some JavaScript implementations) there's a dichotomy between special built-in types (typically scalar value-types) like `int`/`Integer` and `String` compared to user-defined types (typically a Record or Struct type, maybe polymorphic classes and interfaces if you're using a more flexible language), C++ doesn't have this distinction (though it does have special handling for intrinsics like `int`).

With respect to this code you posted that you claim is "without objects":

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int array1[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
}
```

...it actually *does* have objects, it has at least 7 objects:

- Object 1: the `array1` array of type `int[5]` (the "type" of an array in C++ includes its const length)
- Objects 2 through 6: each item in the array is an object of type `int`
- Object 7: the function's return value of type `int` (in this case it's implicit because you didn't explicitly return a value).
- There may be other objects elsewhere in your program defined in header files or compiler-specific files.

Comment: Maybe "a type defined with `class` or `struct`"?

Comment: @juanchopanza I've rewritten my answer to cite the C++ language specification for a precise answer.

Comment: Yeah, I was struggling to understand objects so thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @juanchopanza The standard uses the term "structure type".

Comment: @Galik in which context?

Comment: @juanchopanza In the context of describing a type. For example: *"The struct nullopt_t is an empty structure type..."*.

Comment: @Galik Interesting. There seems to be no definition of "structure type" though. Looks like a potential defect. I also found "struct type", in the context of explaining differences between C++ classes (class or struct) with C++ structs.

Comment: @juanchopanza I think sometimes we let pedantry get in the way of just speaking plain English. It doesn't have to be an "official" term to be accurate and useful.

Comment: @Galik Where's the accuracy if anyone can interpret what it actually means?

Comment: If my question got a lot of downvotes, why is their answer getting upvotes? My question est weird?

Comment: @EmCode The question is based on an incorrect pemise (i.e. that instances of classes are "objects" while scalar value-types are not, which is not true) whereas people always love to upvote answers to c++ questions that refer to the formal language specifications, lol.

Comment: Yea. I was wondering about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, all objects have a type.  All the word "object" means is "an instance of a type".

Let's look at a few examples:

```
int foo;
```

In this case, `foo` is an object who's type is `int`.

```
int foo[5];
```

In this case `foo` is an object who's type is "array of five `int`s".  `foo[n]` is a sub-object of `foo` who's type is `int`.

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
};

Foo foo;
```

In this case, `foo` is an object who's type is `Foo`.  `foo.a` is a sub-object of `foo` who's type is `int`.

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
};

Foo foo[5];
```

In this case `foo` is an object who's type is "array of five `Foo`s".  `foo[n]` is a sub-object of `foo` who's type is `Foo`, and `foo[n].a` is a sub-object of `foo[n]` who's type is `int`.